# ORDS_PUBLIC_USER missing from database

Tags: sql, rest, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-5.1

I installed APEX 5.1.4 with ORDS version 3. Everything works. But I cannot find the `ORDS_PUBLIC_USER`. All other relevant schemas i.e. `APEX_PUBLIC_USER`, `APEX_LISTENER`, `APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER` are available.

Did I miss something?

Comment: sounds like you have to install ords:  java -jar ords.war install

Answer (score 1):

Somehow that didn't work the first time. I did  `java -jar ords.war uninstall` and then a `java -jar ords.war install advanced` and now I can see the `ORDS_PUBLIC_USER` and `ORDS_METADATA` created. Strange.